# Xamarin Forms Picker in IOS will not wrap

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm attempting to make a custom renderer in Xamarin forms so that the text in the picker will wrap for IOS. Android works fine. From reading around it seems I need to do this with a UIPickerViewDelegate. However, when I do this.. the picker just breaks worse than it was broken before and is basically unusable. If I use the delegate, then the picker renders fine, but when you select something. Anything. It's always the first item that get's selected. Select the 10th item and the UI shows the 1st item. It doesn't matter which item you select. The picker somehow always thinks it's the first. I haven't done anything intentionally to affect the selected items. It feels like there's something else I'm supposed to do that these other solutions are not telling me.

Here's my renderer:

```
public class CustomPickerRenderer : PickerRenderer {

protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e) {
  base.OnElementChanged(e);
  if (Control != null) {
    ((UIPickerView)Control.InputView).Delegate = new CustomPickerViewDelegate();
  }
}

protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
  base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
  if (e.PropertyName.Equals("itemssource", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) {
    ((Control.InputView as UIPickerView).Delegate as CustomPickerViewDelegate).ItemSource = Element.ItemsSource;
  }
}
```

}

Here's My UIPickerViewDelegate

```
public class CustomPickerViewDelegate: UIPickerViewDelegate {

public IList ItemSource { get; set; }

public override UIView GetView(UIPickerView pickerView, nint row, nint component, UIView view) {
  UILabel label = new UILabel();
  label.Text = ItemSource[(int)row].ToString();
  label.Lines = 0;
  label.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap;

  return label;
}

public override nfloat GetRowHeight(UIPickerView pickerView, nint component) {
  return 48;
}
```

}

Comment: Hi , could you share two images to explain the wanted and the current shows ?

Comment: Ok. What I want is really simple. I want the picker to be able to pick items other than the first one. How is that not clear? With the above code, every single selection regardless of what's selected results in the first item to be selected. The STR is literally. 1. Click Picker 2. Select anything at random 3. Observe your selection is not what's selected. It's always the first item.

When What I want is: 1. Click Picker 2. Select anything at random 3. Observe that the picker has selected the item i've selected.

Comment: I put this above code in a brand new project that's not modified from a VS2019 stock xamarin forms template and it's broken. There's something I must be missing in the delegate or something.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that . I just want to check the wrapped effect whether is my thought .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked with some part of code in local site ,also found that not set the selected value after clicking `Done` Button . To solve this , we need to custom a **UIToolbar** to override the system one .

In addition , when scrolling end , the value can not be selected automatically .We need to add `Selected` override method inside `CustomPickerViewDelegate` to set selected value for **Control**(`UITextField`) .

The full code of **CustomPickerRenderer** as follow :

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Picker), typeof(CustomPickerRenderer))]
namespace MonkeyApp.iOS
{
    public class CustomPickerRenderer : PickerRenderer
    {
        List<string> itemList;
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control != null)
            {

                //Control.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;

                UITextField textField = Control;
           
                UIPickerView pickerView = textField.InputView as UIPickerView;

                Picker myPicker = Element;
                itemList = myPicker.Items.ToList();

                pickerView.Delegate = new CustomPickerViewDelegate(itemList, textField);

                UIToolbar toolbar = new UIToolbar(new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0,0,UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size.Width,44));
                UIBarButtonItem spaceItem = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace);
                UIBarButtonItem doneButtonItem = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Done);
                doneButtonItem.Clicked += DoneButtonItem_Clicked;
                var bbs = new UIBarButtonItem[] { spaceItem, doneButtonItem };
                toolbar.SetItems(bbs, false);
                Control.InputAccessoryView = toolbar;
            }
        }

        private void DoneButtonItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Control.ResignFirstResponder();
        }
    }

    internal class CustomPickerViewDelegate : UIPickerViewDelegate
    {
        private List<string> itemList;
        private UITextField textField;

        public CustomPickerViewDelegate(List<string> itemList, UITextField textField)
        {
            this.itemList = itemList;
            this.textField = textField;
        }

        public override UIView GetView(UIPickerView pickerView, nint row, nint component, UIView view)
        {
            UILabel label = new UILabel();
            label.Text = itemList[(int)row];
            label.Lines = 0;
            label.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap;

            return label;
        }

        public override nfloat GetRowHeight(UIPickerView pickerView, nint component)
        {
            return 48;
        }

        public override void Selected(UIPickerView pickerView, nint row, nint component)
        {
            textField.Text = itemList[(int)row];
        }
    }
}
```

The effect :

[image]

Comment: This seems to be working! Thanks! New to mobile development and I've been really struggling with this one for some time! Thanks a bunch!